# File creation using an if statement

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a basic logging system to log each call of a class into a file named `log.csv`. I have a string called `logPath` which contains `..\\..\\log.csv` and another string called `logData` which holds the information that I want to write to the log file.

The code I have so far:

```
if (!File.Exists(logPath))
{
    File.Create(logPath);
    StreamWriter writeLog = new StreamWriter(logPath, true);
    writeLog.WriteLine(logData);
    writeLog.Close();

}
else if (File.Exists(logPath))
{
    StreamWriter writeLog = new StreamWriter(logPath, true);
    writeLog.WriteLine(logData);
    writeLog.Close();
}
```

However, when I run the code and the log file doesn't exist, the program crashes but still creates the file `log.csv`, however the data in `logData` isn't written to the file. When I run the program again, because the file exists it has no problem writing each call of the class. When the program crashes at file creation it throws an `IOException`, claiming that the file is being used by another process.

Comment: what do you mean by `crashes`? is there any exception? wrap your code in `try-catch` block and debug catch to see the exception.

Comment: Sounds like antivirus

Comment: BTW: The code does not follow the DRY (don't repeat yourself) clean code principle. Also, the `if` in the `else` should always be true (except someone deleted the file between those two checks).

Comment: I get this error to when I have the specific file opened already => resulting in the famous IOException. Close the file during testing and give the filename a datetime in it making it unique

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the following line (this creates the file and keeps it open, and the next line you are trying to create it again and crashes cuz it has been created and the file is still open):

```
File.Create(logPath);
```

That's why you received the message indicating the fact that the file is in use by another process, when in fact it your own process caused by File.Create

Intact all you need is to replace your entire code with the following (it creates the file if it doesn't exist)

```
using(var writeLog = new StreamWriter(logPath, true))
{
    WriteLog.WriteLine(logData);
    writeLog.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are appending and the StreamWriter already creates the file if it doesn't exist you can simplify your code as below:

```
using (StreamWriter writeLog = new StreamWriter(logPath, true))
{
    writeLog.WriteLine(logData);
    writeLog.Close();
}
```

Comment: I tested the code it works fine. I'd appreciate if the downvoter explains their reason.

Comment: What you state is correct but not what the OP is searching for. Extend your answer with a solution for his problem (not the downvoter I am)

Comment: I tested this solution and it fixes the file is in process exception in my tests. so that is the solution.

Comment: Also proof of that is that the other answer updated as my  exact solution and it got accepted :-)

Comment: you merely had an incomplete answer. I'll +1 it since it is correct but not complete

Comment: @Schuere: Thank you for the +1. But the code block I provided is a complete replacement of the code block OP posted. I don't think I should add more code to his application without any reason.